# Is it possible to add data in a query?

Tags: java, sql

I want to bring a field from a table and add 1 to that field, is it possible?

I tried this way, but the only thing it does is put 1 always.

```
try {
    ps = cc.conectar.prepareStatement("UPDATE personeros SET votos = '" + 1 + 
                                      "' WHERE numero = '" + candidato + "'");
    ps.executeUpdate();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error: " + e);
}
```

Comment: `set votos = votos+1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax you want here is:

```
SET votos = votos + 1
```

Full code:

```
try {
    ps = cc.conectar.prepareStatement("UPDATE personeros SET votos = votos + 1 WHERE numero = ?");
    ps.setInt(1, candidato);
    ps.executeUpdate();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error: " + e);
}
```

As a side note, in my edit I am using a placeholder `?` to which I am binding the value `candidato`.  This is the whole point of using prepared statements, to avoid having to concatenate together literal fragments in your SQL string.

Comment: Thanks you man, its the answer, I will mark it in few minutes.